# How to load fonts and images with Dompdf (laravel-dompdf)?

Tags: laravel-8, dompdf

I have Laravel 8 and laravel-dompdf installed.

In the config/domppdf.php file i have some settings

```
"font_dir" => storage_path('pdf-assets-cache/'),
"font_cache" => storage_path('pdf-assets-cache/'),
"temp_dir" =>  storage_path('pdf-assets-cache/'),
"chroot" => realpath(base_path()),
"pdf_backend" => "PDFLib",
"enable_remote" => true,
"enable_html5_parser" => true,
```

The view:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'TTNorms-Reg';
    src: url('/pdf-fonts/TTNorms-Reg.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('/pdf-fonts/TTNorms-Reg.woff2'),
        url('/pdf-fonts/TTNorms-Reg.woff') format("woff"),
        url('/pdf-fonts/TTNorms-Reg.ttf');
    format("truetype");
}

body {
    color: black !important;
    background: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-family: TTNorms-Reg;
}
```

In my controller i tried

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('frontend.attendees.ticket', $data)
    ->setPaper('a4', 'portrait')
    ->setOptions(['dpi' => 96,
        'isHtml5ParserEnabled' => TRUE,
        'isRemoteEnabled' => TRUE,
        'enable_html5_parser' => TRUE,
        'enable_remote' => TRUE,
        'enable_css_float' => TRUE, 
'chroot' => storage_path('/')]);
```

The view loads perfectly with
`return view('frontend.attendees.ticket', $data);`

But the pdf result is without images and fonts.

When enabling the warnings I get:
`Permission denied on /pdf-fonts/TTNorms-Reg.woff2. The file could not be found under the paths specified by Options::chroot`

Kinda stuck. Any help or hints are much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Solved by adding the utm and cache to the storage/pdf-assets-cache/ folder. The steps:

1. Not needed:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'TTNorms-Reg';
    src: url('/pdf-fonts/TTNorms-Reg.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('/pdf-fonts/TTNorms-Reg.woff2'),
        url('/pdf-fonts/TTNorms-Reg.woff') format("woff"),
        url('/pdf-fonts/TTNorms-Reg.ttf');
    format("truetype");
}
```

2. Download load_font.php
   https://github.com/dompdf/utils/blob/master/load_font.php
3. In terminal

```
php load_font.php TTNorms-Reg public/fonts/TTNorms-Reg.ttf
php load_font.php MG-mono public/fonts/MonumentGrotesk-Mono.ttf
```

4. Copy newly generated .ufm, .ufm.php, dompdf_font_family_cache.php files in
   `vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts/` folder
   to
   `storage/pdf-assets-cache/` folder